# How to convert mp3 to ogg in Python without writing to disk?

Tags: python, audio, mp3, ogg

I need to convert bytes mp3 data to bytes ogg. How can I do it in Python? I've seen many examples to convert it from a file, but I don't want to write it to disk.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
bytes = urlopen("https://url.com/file.mp3").read()
```

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1: Convert online

You can use [online-convert](https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg) service. It has it's own [API](https://apiv2.online-convert.com/) and it supports conversion directly from URL, so you don't even need to read the file into memory.

## Solution 2: Convert locally with temp file

```
import tempfile
from pydub import AudioSegment
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlopen('https://sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3').read()
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
f.write(data)
AudioSegment.from_mp3(f.name).export('result.ogg', format='ogg')
f.close()
```

Comment: I thought about it, but urls attached to my IP address, so I can't upload it((

Comment: What do you mean ”urls attached to IP”? Are your URLs local and not available through the internet?

Comment: yes, so only I can download it, and i don't want to load audio to the internet again, so i searching for converter-library

Comment: I've updated my answer. See solution #2. Your mp3 file will be storing in temp file and will be removed after conversion completed.